# Equivalent for str.join in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a clean way to concatenate an arbitrary number of string series similar to the `' '.join` idiom? If I know the columns I want in advance I can do

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['word1','word2', 'word3']])
df[0] + ' ' + df[1] + ' ' + df[2]

0    word1 word2 word3
```

However I don't know a good way to generalise this to an arbitrary list of columns. The best I have come up with is

```
cols = [0,1,2]
df[cols[0]].str.cat(df[cols[1:]].values.transpose(), sep = ' ')
0    word1 word2 word3
```

But I kind of hate this solution. Maybe there's a way to do it using the overloading of `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind about space at the end of your rows you could use `sum` which is a bit faster then manually typing `df[0] + ' ' + df[1] + ' ' + df[2]`:

```
In [25]: (df + ' ').sum(axis=1)
Out[25]:
0    word1 word2 word3
dtype: object
```

Hovewer, if you need to strip last space then it becomes slower:

```
In [26]: (df + ' ').sum(axis=1).str.strip()
Out[26]:
0    word1 word2 word3
dtype: object
```

**Timing**:

```
In [34]: %timeit (df + ' ').sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 368 us per loop

In [38]: %timeit df[0] + ' ' + df[1] + ' ' + df[2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 482 us per loop

In [40]: %timeit (df + ' ').sum(axis=1).str.strip()
1000 loops, best of 3: 556 us per loop

In [47]: %timeit df[cols[0]].str.cat(df[cols[1:]].values.transpose(), sep = ' ')
1000 loops, best of 3: 870 us per loop

In [49]: %timeit df[[0,1,2]].apply(' '.join, axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 937 us per loop
```

Comment: this is great, thanks anton, definately don't care about an extra space at the end, this is feeding into a tokenizer which will take care of all of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could `apply` along `axis=1` after selecting your columns (here I'll specify them manually, but you could use `cols` instead):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['word1','word2', 'word3']])
>>> df
       0      1      2
0  word1  word2  word3
>>> df[[0,1,2]].apply(' '.join, axis=1)
0    word1 word2 word3
dtype: object
```

Comment: this is an elegant solution, unfortunately it's 10-100 times slower than using the vectorized `+`, any ideas how to use the vectorized operation?